# Simulating tournament results with R

Tags: r, simulation, probability

aIn `R`, how do one run a tournament simulation?

I have the probabilities of each teams chance of winning against the other pairs, for example:

```
prob_res <- matrix(round(runif(64),2), 8, 8)
prob_res[lower.tri(prob_res, diag = TRUE)] <- 0
prob_res <- as.data.frame(prob_res)
colnames(prob_res) <- 1:8
rownames(prob_res) <- 1:8
```

Which would mean something like this:

```
  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
1 0 0.76 0.35 0.81 0.95 0.08 0.47 0.26
2 0 0.00 0.24 0.34 0.54 0.48 0.53 0.54
3 0 0.00 0.00 0.47 0.51 0.68 0.50 0.80
4 0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.52 0.59 0.38 0.91
5 0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.88 0.64
6 0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.23 0.65
7 0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.77
8 0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

The next step would be to run a set of simulations, say `n = 100000`

First the quarter-finals (best out of 3):

```
1 vs 8
2 vs 7
3 vs 6
4 vs 5
```

And then the winners of each pair face off in the semi-finals:

```
1-8 winner VS 4-5 winner
2-7 winner VS 3-6 winner
```

Winners move on to the final. All is best out of 3.

What approach/package could I use to run bracket simulations? I did find a package called [mRchmadness](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mRchmadness/) but it's too specific to handle this simulation.

Comment: Why assume there is a ready-made package to run bracket simulations? Even if there were, asking for library recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It shouldn't be too hard to write your own. But, simply asking how to do so in R is an overly-broad question. Start writing code and ask a more focused question if you run into trouble.

Comment: The tournament is described fully above. There are 8 teams and they play as stated. Team 1 vs team 8, etc. I assumed I need some type of package to run a simulation (of any kind), I'm sorry if I came across wrong. Moreover, I do not feel the question is overly-broad as there are only these 8 teams that I need to simulate in they way described. I haven't done any simulations in R so I'm starting from scratch here, hence the question.

Comment: It is broad in the sense that writing a simulation from scratch requires writing a program. You could start by writing a function which takes a pair of teams and simulates a round of best out of 3, returning the winner. Then write another function which simulates a single tournament. Then write a function that calls that 100,000 times, gathering whatever statistics that you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created some dummy code that can help you figure out how to do it. The code is not optimized at all, but it is quite linear for you to understand how to do it.

```
prob_res <- matrix(round(runif(64),2), 8, 8)
prob_res[lower.tri(prob_res, diag = TRUE)] <- 0
prob_res <- as.data.frame(prob_res)
colnames(prob_res) <- 1:8
rownames(prob_res) <- 1:8
prob_res

## Total number of combinations
posscombi<-t(combn(1:8, 2))   

## This function gives you winners of the match with n repetitionmatches against every other team possible combination of teams. 
## It "reproduces" like the whole league assuming winning probabilities are static.

League <- function(repetitionMatches, posscomb , prob_res)
    {
    TotalVect<-integer(0)
    for(i in 1:nrow(posscomb)){
        pair <- posscomb[i,]
        Vect<-sample(pair, 
                     size = repetitionMatches, 
                     prob = c(prob_res[pair[1], pair[2]], 1-prob_res[pair[1], pair[2]]),
                     replace = TRUE)
        TotalVect <- c(TotalVect, Vect)
        }    
    return(table(TotalVect))
    }

Result<-League(100,posscomb = posscombi, prob_res= prob_res) 

Myorder<-order(Result)
### Quarters 
pair1<- c(names(Result)[Myorder[c(1,8)]]) 
pair2<- c(names(Result)[Myorder[c(2,7)]])
pair3<- c(names(Result)[Myorder[c(3,6)]])
pair4<- c(names(Result)[Myorder[c(4,5)]])
## This function gives you the results to n matches (being 3 in the example)
PlayMatch<-function(pairs, numMatches){
    Res <-sample(pairs, size = numMatches, 
       prob = c(prob_res[pairs[1], pairs[2]], 1-prob_res[pairs[1], pairs[2]]),
       replace = TRUE)
    return(table(Res))
        }
# Results of the matches
winner1<-PlayMatch(pairs = pair1, 3)
winner2<-PlayMatch(pairs = pair2, 3)
winner3<-PlayMatch(pairs = pair3, 3)
winner4<-PlayMatch(pairs = pair4, 3)

## Semis
#Choosing the winning teams
pair1<- c(names(winner1)[which.max(winner1)],names(winner2)[which.max(winner2)])
pair2<- c(names(winner3)[which.max(winner3)],names(winner4)[which.max(winner4)])
winner1<-PlayMatch(pairs = pair1, 3)
winner2<-PlayMatch(pairs = pair2, 3)

## Final
# Same as before
pair1<- c(names(winner1)[which.max(winner1)],names(winner2)[which.max(winner2)])
winner1<-PlayMatch(pairs = pair1, 3)
paste0( "team ",names(winner1)[which.max(winner1)],  " is the winner!")
```